# Can a relativizer be modified by PP phrase

Tags: prepositional-phrases, relative-pronouns

> The level of responsibility **which** the client ***carries for the whole development process*** with time & materials is much higher than with fixed-price or milestone projects.

It can be understood that a gap exists behind the verb **carries**

> The level of responsibility which the client carries _______ for the whole development process ...

So the relativizer **which** serves as the object of **carries**.

And since the PP pharse **for the whole development process** follows the gap (known as **which**),

is it right to say that the PP phrase (which acts as an adjective) modifies the relativizer **which**?

Comment: Not quite: The PP does not function as modifier, but as complement of 'gap', which is co-indexed to "which" and "level of responsibility".

Comment: @BillJ Thanks, just to make sure I am understanding your answer correctly. "for the whole development process" is a complement of both the relativizer **which** and **level of responsibility** ?

Comment: Not quite: syntactically, the PP is a complement of 'gap', which is anaphorically linked to "which". i.e. "which" is antecedent for the gap. "Which" derives its interpretation from "level of responsibility".

Comment: @BillJ Thanks,sorry for asking one more question. If I ignore the main clause, the relative clause originally would be "The client carries the level of responsibility for the whole development process..." . Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Since when does "carry" take a complement? Isn't the PP just a modifier (of the clause)?